# Why layout “jumps” when scrollbar is showing on page center using margin auto only on some computers?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar, centering

Know problem:
Scrollbar is shrinking width of page and elements center using `margin:auto` are moving.

Tests:
I checked it on few computers and get surprising results. On some of them layout isn't moving.

Regardless of browser(if problem is appearing it affect all browsers if not all browsers are fine).

It doesn't matter if it is ios or windows (the same like with browsers).

Question:
Why only few computers are affected?

PS.
I checked scroll setting they are the same.

jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ujDZv/

screenshot:
http://jsfiddle.net/YcmT9/4/

Comment: do the computers have different screen resolutions and dimensions (normal/widescreen) ?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle exemple please ?

Comment: @florin.prisecariu Nope. The same resolution.

Comment: some older browsers start with a greyed out scroller on the left so when your page is too long and the scroller is "added", it doesn't shift your page content.  However newer browsers all seem to have removed this which is why you get the movement when a scroll bar is added.  If you want to add the grey out scroller back in you can use: `body {overflow-y:scroll}`

Comment: @Pete it is affecting all browser on that computers. for e.g latest chrome.

Comment: @AlexDom added jsfiddle

Comment: Thank's @Kinga it's more clear now. Problem is that ui elements are depending on Os

Comment: @AlexDom Nope :( I tested it on few iOS (same version) and 2 machines problem occurred. Then it isn't OS related problem. 

On computers which are not affected it even work on VM IE.

I posted screenshot form IE because only way to reproduce it on my computer is to run it on browserstack IE.

Comment: I'm investigating (Smashing magazine, A list a part & Css tricks ^^) but i don't think it's something you can repare with css :[ i saw this (not finished yet) http://css-tricks.com/eliminate-jumps-in-horizontal-centering-by-forcing-a-scroll-bar/

Comment: It is extra crazy right now because it start to affect my computer right now... 

http://jsfiddle.net/YcmT9/2/

Comment: @AlexDom Done my research (all you listed, only old articles from 2007...) but no answer why it is only few computers and why it started happening to me right now (now I'm tying find what conditions have changed)

Comment: i don't think that i can help you more sorry (it's a old problem and an article don't need to be new to be useful, you never know what you gonna learn :) )

Comment: @AlexDom Thx any way:) With old stuff I had in mind that in 2007 jumps in that kind of situation was normal on all browsers and all os. It was known bug but right now it is showing up only in some conditions and I want to know what they are because maybe there is different way to change it than add overflow-y:scroll.
taste)